# Electron app shows child process error and it doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, electron, child-process, electron-builder

I am building electron app with laravel project. When I run the app with "npm start", it works fine. However, when I package the project, it shows "ChildProcess" error and the app doesn't work. What does that mean, and what should I do ?
[image: t]

Note: I built my app basing on this tutorial https://github.com/laravelarticle/laravel-electron

Answer (score 1):

Don't include your PHP folder inside asar package.
Can't access to spawn.

Use this to build your application properly.

> **asar** = true AsarOptions | Boolean - Whether to package the
> application’s source code into an archive, using Electron’s archive
> format.
>
> Node modules, that must be unpacked, will be detected automatically,
> you don’t need to explicitly set asarUnpack - please file an issue if
> this doesn’t work.

> **smartUnpack** = true Boolean - Whether to automatically unpack
> executables files.

> **ordering** String

> **asarUnpack** Array | String -
> A glob patterns relative to the app directory, which specifies which
> files to unpack when creating the asar archive.